# Rails + rails-api: Circular Dependency with Helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rails-api

I have a module ApiHelper in the helpers api_helper folder that's causing a bit of mayhem. In controllers/api/v1 I have two controllers, both of which have

```
include ApiHelper
```

The exact error is:

```
/Users/WEF6/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:461:in `load_missing_constant': Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant APIHelper (RuntimeError)
```

I'm thinking this issue is happening because I have an api_controller that is set up like this using rails-api:

```
class ApiController < ActionController::API
```

and my normal application controller set up like this

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
```

The api controllers inherit from the ApiController, while my normal App controllers inherit from the ApplicationController.

Or it might be something much more simple; thoughts?

Comment: Did you managed to solve this?

Comment: No, I ended up moving the methods I wanted to be helpers into separate modules and put them in the concerns folder. Examples are the module Presentable, Decryptable, and Parsable.

Comment: In my case it was a helper called `TableHelper` just changed the name to `MyTableHelper` and all was good.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I ran into a similar problem recently. In my case the problem was the addition of an inflection acronym for **'API'** to `config/initializers/inflections.rb`.

All I had to do to solve this was to rename `ApiHelper` to `APIHelper` and the problem was solved.